# jQuery muiltiselect is not working with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, select, multiselect.js

I'm using jQuery multiple select with checkbox options here is my control

```
<div id="main-wrapper" ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="ngCtrl" style="background:#efefef; border-radius:5px; padding:15px; margin:15px 0px;">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="rolename">Role Name</label>
        <select id="dates-field2" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="cheese">Cheese</option>
            <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
            <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
            <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
            <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
            <option value="onions">Onions</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

But the problem is that this control is placed inside the `ng-controller` and `ng-app` so of AngularJS. So when I open the controller and checked the checkbox inside it that it is not working like it suppose to work to do.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery? There are different multiselects which perfectly with angularjs apps and should be used: http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main Or this one: http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main

Comment: Any feedback m8?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery extensions causing a lot of problems in interaction with AngularJS. You may going to check this nice article about - [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background). You need to create a directive or just use a select which is compatible with AngularJS. You may going to use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) which based on select2.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
  <ui-select multiple tagging ng-model="vm.selected" theme="bootstrap">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Pick one...">{{$item.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="val in vm.values | filter: $select.search track by val.value">
      <div ng-bind="val.value | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
</div>
```

#### > [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m27qw2fL/)

Answer (score -1):

remove attribute  multiple="multiple" and try with

multiple="true"